# Hide and Show based on focus of the select option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, hide

**page1.php**

In this the select option is selected options are send to the **page.php**

forget the values which are selected in this page1.php

I am trying to hide and show the input box when the mouse click or focus on the selected id i.e..select option html tags

```
   <html>
    <script>         
    $('#cic_name').focus(function(){                                
            var array = [];
            $('.tg_value_select option:checked').each(function(i,value){                                    
                array[i] = $(this).val();                                           
        });                                                                             
            if(array.length>0)
            {
                $("#cic_name").hide();    
                    $("#show_cic").load("checkbox.php",{values:array},function(){});        
           }
          else {        
          $("#cic_name").show();              
        }          
    });             
    </script>



    <select multiple="multiple" id="tg_value_select" class="tg_value_select">
        <option value="child" selected="selected">Children</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" id="cic_name" name="cic"  placeholder="CiC Name">

    </html>
```

**page2.php**

After the page2.php loads through the ajax than the javascript code which is focusing on this id **tg_value_select** this id : **cic_value_select** show be hide and input id : **cic_name** should show...

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){

    $(".tg_value_select").focus(function(){

                $(".cic_value_select").hide();

                        $("#cic_name").show();
                });
    });

    </script>

    <select title="Basic example"  class="cic_value_select" >

        <option value="child" selected="selected">Children</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>

</html>
```

After the page2.php loads, than the user select the select option i.e..**tg_value_select** the second select option **cic_value_select** has to hide and input box has to show...

The focusing on the select option is no working please help..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to do a focus on option tag it will not work. You might have create a custom select box using divs. however if you are trying to change when clicking or entering on the selected item use .change in jQuery

Comment: Yes, I tried using on change..function also its not working...and after the ajax loads the page2.php loads than, if the  user tries to click on the page1.php i.e.. select option than the second select html tag should hide and input box should show.....please read question...

Comment: you cannot use focus anyway. 

What you can do is after the select loads use your logic to hide and show.. Either use document.ready or load the javascript before the </body> tag

Comment: yes , present I have taken the input box so that I can focus on the input element only, but If the user focus on the select element on the first page1.php

Comment: Than second select option in the page2.php which loads through the ajax call...it should be hide and show the input box...this is the logic....